# Alternative to using ArcGIS Online Geocoding

Tags: geocoding, arcgis-online, address, free-software

I have 1.4 million addresses that I need to batch geocode. I can't find a free service to do so. Does anyone know of something out there that I can use? Oh, the service needs to be were I can upload a file in a .txt file formate, not a copy and paste. Copy and paste services crash the 661 mb size file.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) from OpenStreetMap:

> Nominatim (from the Latin, 'by name') is a tool to search OSM data by name and address and to generate synthetic addresses of OSM points (reverse geocoding). It can be found at http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org

You may need to write the wrapper functionality to allow uploading of a text file.

Answer (score 1):

You could try MMQGIS plugin in QGIS. It uses Google API for geo-coding and reverse geo-coding.

http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mmqgis/

Go to MMQGIS tab> Transfer > Geocode CSV from Google.

It takes CSV file as input but output geocoded file and not-found-addresses file in case of no address found on google map. Make sure your CSV is in the right format for this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

[SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com) has a [Bulk Address Validation Tool for Lists](https://smartystreets.com/products/list) service that is designed to do exactly what you're looking for: You upload a list (.csv, .txt, or .xls) and a few minutes later you download the output files, which give 45 data points, including geocode data, for each address.

Our [pricing](https://smartystreets.com/pricing) is very competitive, with no minimum purchase price, and if you're a startup or a nonprofit, then you can probably get our service for [free](https://smartystreets.com/free-address-verification).